# Why I can't put a height var instead of a num in the container?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, containers, height

I have this container that contains a Streambuilder that contains a ListView.builder(), I want the container to adapt to different heights of different phones logically, don't know why, but in this container I can't put anything in the height method except a pure obviuos number, see when I put a var the whole container disappear.

**Code:**

```
var device_data = MediaQueryData();
    var size = device_data.size;
    var height = size.height;
return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: height * 0.7,
          child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
            stream: _store
                .collection('Khatma Collection')
                .document('Khatma 1')
                .collection('Videos')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    var link = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link'];
                    var uploader = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Uploader'];
                    var likes = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Likes'];
                    var like = likes.toString();
                    bool liked;
                    if (int.parse(like) > 0) {
                      liked = true;
                    } else if (int.parse(like) == 0) {
                      liked = false;
                    }
                    ..............
```

Comment: could you print the value of height? It looks like you wanted MediaQuery.of(context).size.height instead of MediaQueryData().height

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake and thanks for the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the `context`.

Have you tried this ?

```
Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7
    ...
)
```